# How do I pass options (to didFinishLaunchingWithOptions) to the app I activate from my tweak?

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak

I have a tweak that's loaded into SpringBoard and activates an app specified from external sources.

How do I pass any arguments to the app I activate? SBUIController::activateApplicationFromSwitcher() doesn't seem to have any provisions to to that, as well as SBApplication.

Background: I need to pass a file:// url to mobile safari. I've got file:// for mobile safari tweak installed, however it doesn't register file:// scheme with mobile safari, so openURL doesn't work.

Another option would be to extend mobile safari by teaching it how to respond to file:// urls. Can't seem to find what I need to hook for that.

Comment: you can pass command line args to Safari by using the execve or system functions, but I'm not sure it takes the URL to be opened as a command line argument.

Comment: AFAIK apps lunched without SB knowing about them are invisible. I'll test this. Any other ideas?

Comment: For the hook, can't you ask the developer of `com.bigboss.safaripatch`, the `file://` tweak, for the source code? I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: @Cole Johnson: just wrote Jay an e-mail, we'll see

Comment: Here's the file:// source: http://svn.saurik.com/repos/menes/trunk/tweaks/fsms/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *is* possible to do this. First, you have to edit MobileSafari's Info.plist so that file:// is added to the url schemes. Second, you have to override the application:openURL: method with mobilesubstrate to handle this address. This will require some reverse engineering to figure out how to do correctly, but it can be done.

Comment: also, figure out how the url scheme registration works. then you could override those

Answer (score 0):

The way Cydia works may be of intrest to you.

The executable for Cydia itself it `MobileCydia` AFAIK, and SpringBoard launches `Cydia`, which is actually a bash file:

```
#!/bin/bash
C=/${0}
C=${C%/*}
declare -a flags
[[ :${DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES}: == */MobileSubstrate.dylib: ]] && flags[${#flags[@]}]=--  substrate#!/bin/bash
exec "${C:-.}"/MobileCydia "${flags[@]}" -- "$@" 2>>/tmp/cydia.log
```

The piece of code that actually launches Cydia is the `exec` command. What Cydia does is parse the arguments from there. This allows Cydia to hook MobileSubstrate, which all tweaks need.

Hope this helps!

Comment: But you can't make Safari read the URL like this if it was not implemented as such.

Comment: I wonder if mobilesafari looks for urls in the dictionary passed to didFinishLaunchingWithOptions()?

Comment: that bash script is not about didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:. This passes arguments to to main()